# How to debug a failed Gaussian IRC calculation?

Tags: computational-chemistry

During IRC calculation I found the following error message. Anybody can help me?

```
IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC

Error in corrector energy =          -0.0000002157

 Magnitude of corrector gradient =     0.0003105753

 Magnitude of analytic gradient =      0.0003306121

 Magnitude of difference =             0.0001786220

 Angle between gradients (degrees)=   32.1573

 Pt  9 Step number  20 out of a maximum of  20

 CORRECTOR INTEGRATION CONVERGENCE:

   Recorrection delta-x convergence threshold:    0.010000

   Delta-x Convergence NOT Met
 Maximum number of corrector steps exceded.

 Error termination via Lnk1e in /home/adhikary/g09/l123.exe at Sun Aug 21 05:49:50 2016.
```

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. While questions about computational chemistry are on topic, questions about the usage of programs are only to a limited extend on topic. Apart from this, some very important information is missing, e.g. the program you are using, the input, what kind of molecule, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us for a full debug solution.

Answer (score 7):

According to the output, it seems like OP is using Gaussian 09 software package. And according to the error message, the problem is that at 9th step of IRC procedure, Gaussian could not optimize the geometry in 20 steps (which is the default number). I suggest first to increase the number of geometry optimization iterations for each and every IRC step by using the `MaxCycle=N` option as follows:

```
IRC=(...,MaxCycle=100)
```